# Is there a reliable way to set Reply-to and Return-path when using MIME with smtp backend to send email?

Tags: php, email

I'm trying to refine the email functionality of our website and started to build reports, unsubscribe options, etc. The problem is have is that I can't reliably send bounces to an address of my choosing.

I want clients to be able to send newsletters that bounce back to a specific addres while still replying to the sender address so that I can then count the bounces and build my reports from it; while the client can still see replies without being cluttered by bounced emails. Is there a way to reliably do that? (i found that google, for example, won't take my reply-to and return-path headers no matter what I do)

I thuoght about getting the clients to set up another address for mass emails that can bounce (so they don't have to worry about their company emails being probed by my scripts) but then what if they want to see replies to their mass emails?

In short, is there a way to send emails with specific reply-to and return-path that will be correctly interpreted by the majority of the email servers?

The only condition is, it has to be authenticated smtp.

Comment: Just a note, Reply-To is interpreted by the email client and not the smtp server. The user can override this if he wants to. So, not reliable whatever you do.

Comment: MDAs (Mail Delivery Agents) tend to remove those if they find them "bogus", ie. not reflecting the domain the mail comes From (last reverse path).

Comment: Then the solution seems to be to ask the clients to create a "bounce gathering" address on the same domain and having them forward everything to us for processing so that we don't have to read their own address.

Comment: If you have the option, you could try to implement custom headers X-headers. Then you can provide a custom return-path. This of course require you have programmatic access to the smtp server to parse emails for these. ie:

X-Myreturnpath: bouncer@hymn.to. But again, the email client _can_ strip those out, so.. :-|

Comment: But would that work if the clients use their own corporate/google/yahoo emails to send them. Also, I don't personally have access to the servers so I'll have to ask the guy that manages it. Would the bounce gathering addresses work?

Comment: It seem that your setup is not local so that would be very hard. You would need a central system to accomplish this. It will also be a challenge to ask client to implement custom headers, either they don't have technical understanding or it will be forgotten from time to time. If you can convince your client to use a centralized system (ie. web based newsletter generator) you would be able to use a specific client email they gave you access to to add custom headers or even return-path to their domain. However, I know from experience in similar situation that that is a long path (and long shot)

Comment: Well the way it works now is: I send the emails using php (in this case MIME with a smtp backend) and their own email details (encrypted email addresses/passwords). So I can set the headers for them but I can't force them to use the same email client. Management would slap me if I even suggested that.

Comment: It's a classic problem with the email reporting. Some hides an invisible image in the email template which call a server to generate image. <img src="http://myserver.com/getimg?emailid=xxxx" ..> and on your server in the getimg you log the id for stats and return a ghost image (a 2x2 transparent gif for instance). But even this is only so good and not reliable as the user can chose to prevent loading external images.

Comment: Yep, I use that and other tricks to detect opened/clicked emails but bounces just stumped me. The only thing i have left is to report them as number_of_sent_emails - every_other_type = bounced. Was hoping for a more detailed report...